# For loop in R for dataframe column

Tags: r

I am trying to apply a loop to extract vectors from dataframe columns. But failing. Can anyone help me

```
> df <- data.frame(sym = c("ABC","CGF","DFG"))
> com_list <- c(1:3)
for (j in com_list)
{
    com <- c()
    com <- c(com[j], paste0(df$sym[j], collapse=","))
}
> com
[1] "DFG"
```

Expected output

```
> com
"ABC,CGF,DFG"
```

Comment: `com <- paste0(df$sym, collapse = ',')`

Answer (score 1):

For every iteration, first job i.e. `com <- c()` empties the `com` and then pastes ith element.  So the output you are getting is only last element.

If you want to do it through for loop, take `com <- c()` outside of the loop and do it like this.

```
df <- data.frame(sym = c("ABC","CGF","DFG"))
com_list <- c(1:3)
com <- c()
for (j in com_list){
  
  com <- c(com, paste0(df$sym[j], collapse=","))
 }
com

[1] "ABC" "CGF" "DFG"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, loop is not necessary.

```
paste0(df$sym[com_list],collapse=",")
# "ABC,CGF,DFG"
```